# coThe redirect doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, redirect

```
http://mywebsite.com/thor-3
```

If I use javascript to redirect links above to yourwebsite.org/movie, the url will become:

```
http://yourwebsite.org/movie?file=thor-3
```

Why ? How to remove ?file=thor-3 ?

My code redirect :

```
<script>window.location.href = "http://yourwebsite.org/movie";</script>
```

Comment: whats your redirect code?

Comment: in terms of the redirection the ?file shouldn't make a difference. my guess is that you simply have a file button or some additional javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you have redirection in the htaccess file in .org domain which redirecting your /movie/thor-3 link to /movie?file=thor-3